# css anchor div to foot of page

Tags: html, css, layout

I may bounce my head off the wall shortly, I can't believe that something as stupid as this has utterly defeated me ... therefore I turn to you, Stack Overflow ... for guidance and enlightenment.

---

**Problem:** Sit div at foot of page, 100% width, outside of any sort of wrapper.
**Proposed Solution:** http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Implementation with content: http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign/index_content.html
Implementation with no content: http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign/index.html

with content -> Good, works nicely
no content = bad, footer sits exactly height of footer below the viewport.

---

I really would appreciate your input into this, it's completely vexed me for the past hour. I wholly expect some form of ridicule :)

---

**Clarification:** Footer should be attached to bottom of the viewport if there is not enough content to fill the page. It should move down beyond the bottom of the viewport if there is sufficient amount of content.

Thanks!
Foxed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is probably what you are looking for:

http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/

Comment: I love you. Forever and ever.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if I didn't interpret the question correctly, but are you talking about placing the footer on the bottom of the page?

Try this:

```
#footer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 150px;  
   position: fixed; 
   bottom: 0px; 
   left: 0px; 
}
```

If you want the footer to stay in one place, change the `position` attribute to `absolute`.

Comment: Ah sorry - I should have been clearer, I need the footer to remain with the flow of the document - I don't want it fixed to the bottom of the page if there is content there. index_content.html is how it should work if there is enough content on the page to push the footer beyond the bottom of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

This may help the next person implementing the accepted answer (from fortysevenmedia.com) while using Next.js.

You will want to change

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

to

```
html, body, #__next {
    height: 100%;
}
```

(`#__next` is the container div that Next puts just inside `<body>`, which therefore wraps both the container div and footer div that the accepted answer recommends - unless you give it height, the answer won't work).